# Jenkins pipeline. Files disappear after running parallel stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm running a set of parallel stages to do some code checks. Then after the first batch of parallel stages have run, I'm running another batch of parallel stages to check the outputs of the code analysis tools. The pipeline looks like this from the top level:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
    ...
    }
    options {
        ...
        parallelsAlwaysFailFast() }
    stages {
        stage("Verify") {...}
        stage("Set Node") {
            agent {label "${VAR}"}
            stages{
                stage ('Workspace checkout'){...}
                stage ('QA scan') {
                    parallel {
                        stage ('Tool1 Scan') {
                            steps{
                                scan1()
                            }
                        }
                        stage ('Tool2 Scan') {
                            steps{
                                scan2()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage ('QA check') {
                    parallel {
                        stage ('Tool1 check') {
                            steps{
                                analysis1()
                            }
                        }
                        stage ('Tool2 check') {
                            steps{
                                analysis2()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage ('build') {...}
}}}}
```

scan1() will generate some output files that we copy into /tmp folder. They are not kept into the workspace that occurs when checking out. We have only one node for the whole pipeline, not several for the parallel stages.

For my surprise, when we enter into the QA block, I try to access the /tmp folder where we place the files in the first parallel batch of stages but there is nothing there. It looks like Jenkins keeps track not only of the filesystem in workspace, but actually the whole filesystem. This is a surprise for me as we have only one node.

I have thought about stashing and unstashing but I thought moving files to common filesystem areas should have done the trick.

Why my output files generated in a parallel stage in the first set out of workspace are not there anymore when running another set of parallel stages in a second set?